# Fragment transactions android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a question regarding fragment transactions. I have three fragments in my `AuthenticationActivity` which I am removing and adding based on user clicks:

- welcome fragment,
- login fragment,
- signup fragment

I'm having a hard time understanding what happens when the orientation changes and when I remove a fragment and add another fragment.

**Question 1:** When I change the orientation I am checking if my fragment is null and then if my fragment is visible. It says the fragment is not null and fragment is not visible even though I can see the fragment in screen.

**Question 2:** When I remove the present fragment and add another fragment and change the orientation and checking if the previous fragment is null.
Even though I removed the previous fragment it says fragment is not null but not visible. I don't understand this.

It would be great if someone help me with these issues.

```
public class AuthenticationActivity extends Activity implements
        OnClickAuthentication, LoginInterface, SignupInterface {
    private final static String TAG = "AuthenticationActivity";
    private final static String WELCOMETAG = "WelcomeFragmentTAG";
    private final static String LOGINTAG = "LoginFragmentTAG";
    private final static String SIGNUPTAG = "SignupFragmentTAG";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_authentication);
        Log.d(TAG, "in onCreate");
        Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(WELCOMETAG);
        if (fragment == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "welcome fragment is null in onCreate");
            getFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.authentication_parent0_linear,
                            new WelcomeFragment(), WELCOMETAG).commit();
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "welcome fragment is not null in onCreate");
            if (fragment.isVisible()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "welcome fragment is visible");
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "welcome fragment is not visible");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the lifecycles of `Activity` and `Fragment`: [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

The `Fragment` becomes visible when the `Activity` is resumed.

Comment: Is the fragment not visible in onCreate??

Comment: And also why is the removed fragment not returning null??

Comment: I assume that the transaction has not been "handled" yet when you check if it has been removed.

Comment: Glad I could help out! Please mark my answer as correct if your problems are resolved.